# Why does floor() give unexpected result in r?

Tags: r, floating-point, floor

Here is some output from r:

```
> (567.8 - floor(567.8)) * 10
[1] 8
> x <-(567.8 - floor(567.8)) * 10
> floor(x)
[1] 7
```

I would have though the last value would return 8, especially when `floor(8)` returns `8`.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can get around it?